# I have a table with over 500 columns , I need to get the total size of each row to find how many rows are exceeding certain size

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used:

```
select
LENGTH(column1)+
LENGTH(column2)+
LENGTH(column3)+
..
..
as max_length from cmscomponent;
```

This query returns all null values assuming thats because some columns are NULL, I need a way to avoid NULLs and return size of the remaining columns summed up for each row..

Comment: 500 columns? are you sure about your table design?

Comment: you could use nvl(column1,0) if in oracle

Comment: use `coalesce(length(column1),0) + coalesce(length(column2),0) ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull.

```
select
IFNULL(LENGTH(column1),0)+
IFNULL(LENGTH(column2),0)+
IFNULL(LENGTH(column3),0)+
..
..
as max_length from cmscomponent;
```